# What backend to use for a location based android app?

Tags: android, backend

I'm planning to develop a location based Android app. The app needs to store location information such as currentLocation, location info of an address i.e latitude and longitude of each as well as other user info such as name, sex, age etc which i believe i can extract from a fb or g+ login. The app will also include a chat functionality which will allow its users to communicate.

I'm comfortable with Java, but haven't used PHP. But i don't mind spending time learning it if that is the best option in building a backend.

I was wondering if i could use the GAE for the same. I also came across parse.com which can be used as a backend. There may be other options too, which i may not have explored. I'm new to android app development. This will be my first app.  Kindly suggest a backend which suits my needs the best. All kinds of inputs are welcomed!

Comment: I would particularly want to know about parse.com as a backend for my app and its programming requisites.

Answer (score 1):

I work at [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io). It is a backend-as-a-service and it has support for geolocated data and users authentication using Facebook, Google+, Twitter and more external services (additionally to email + password authentication).

Furthermore, we have plans to release an Open Source version this year.

If you need further information we will be glad to assist you :)

Comment: This aged well.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right or wrong answer to this really.

For myself, I've been learning and using Python and MongoDB.  There are so many web/cloud based hosting services that learning and using a free account for your development shouldn't be a problem no matter your language choice.

If you are writing the app in Java, maybe you want your cloud system to also be similar using JavaScript such as NodeJS.